# Pyinstaller throws "Import Error:requests> 2.18.0 is required by the google.resumable media.requests subpackage."

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, pyinstaller

I used pyinstaller to convert my .py file to .exe, but as i try to execute the exe it throws the following error:

> Import Error:requests> 2.18.0 is required by the google.resumable media.requests subpackage.

My pip version is : pip 19.1.1

here's the code i used :

```
pyinstaller -F AdminPanel.py
```

i tried installing it using pip, but it says that its already installed.

Thanks in advance

Complete Error is:

```
Resources.Distribution Plot Found: The requests-2.18.0 distribution was not found and is required by the

The above exception as the direct cause of the following exception:

Network

Traceback (most recent call last):
File AdninPanelUI.py, line 11, in module>
File "d: Nother stuffiapplications\python\installation\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod83_importer
627, in exec_module

exec(bytecode, module. dict)
File "site-packages\google cloud storage__init__.py", line 39, In <module>
File "d: other stufflapplications\python\installation\llb\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimode3_importer
627, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module. dict)
File site-packages\google cloud storage\blob.py", line 44, in <module
File "d: other stuff applications\python\installation\lib site-packages\PyInstaller loader\pyimode3_importer
627, in exec_module

exec(bytecode, module. dict)
File "site-packages\google\resumable_media\requests_init_.py", 1ine 673, in <module>
File string", 1ine 3, in raise from

ImportError:requests
2.18.e is required by the google.resumable_media.requests
subpackage.
It can be installed via
pip Install google-resumable-media[requests).
17008) Failed to execute script Admin Panel
```

Comment: Did you use the `-U` for upgrade when running `pip`? What version is already installed? Include the entire message from pip as you could have a dependency issue where one package requires version X but another package requires version Y.

Comment: The changes has been done to the question. Refer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i fixed the error :

Made a hook(python file) named it

> hook-google.resumable_media.requests

and the content of it is as follow :

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata
datas = copy_metadata('requests')
```

Then after just past this file to the hooks folder inside pyinstaller where all the other hooks are.

Hope it fixed the error for you.